# How much should I rebase interactively?

Tags: git, github, translation, git-fork, rebasing

I would like to translate a larger book hosted at Github. The orignal repo would be forked by me and I'll usually do my work on my own at a new branch. So nobody would really care about a changed history while rebasing interactively.

Sometimes a lot of commits only contain chunks of the translation and mess uo the history of commits. How much commits should I squash and pick to create a clean history? One commit per chapter or a few of them?

The commits will be merged back into the orignal repo where all translations are accumulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as you want (assuming your repo is not shared with anyone else). 
Bear in mind that you are rewriting the history every time you squash commits.

Comment: My commits will be merged back into the orignal repo, or to be more exactly into a  language specific subfolder.

Comment: If your commits have been already merged to the main repo then I would avoid squashing commits.

Comment: I haven't began the translation yet but I planned to commit into my fork repo, squash the there commits and after finishing the whole translation I'll make a pull request.

Comment: I see. Well, if you plan to push only once (the whole translation) I would have 1 commit per chapter. Or maybe you would have a branch for each chapter and then merge all chapters into "yourLanguage" branch.

Comment: Or maybe a combination of both. So I would create a new branch `mytranslation` as a copy from master. `mytranslation` has also subbranches for each chapter which would allow me to translate them independently. With the time I could rebase the chapter branch into a single commit.

Finally - when everything is translated and proof-read - would you merge or rebase? Merging creates a sort of  'meaningless' commit per merge. Otherwise I could rebase `chapter1`, `chapter2` and so on and create a nice linear commit history.

Comment: yep, I like your approach, if you plan to create a pull request with everything then I would follow your approach (With the rebase)